# How to upload an image to a Laravel 9 REST API using Nuxt3?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a form which is used to send data to a REST API. I store all data inside an object and send it using the built in useFetch() function.

```
const submitResponse = await useFetch(`${config.API_BASE_URL}/products`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: productData.value,
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userData.token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    }
});
```

When I console.log the object everything looks good. [Image of the logged object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H63gx.png)

But when Inspecting the request in the Network tab it's missing the image object and I receive a 422 response code:
[Image of the request payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK8ZD.png)

Here is the code for the function on the backend

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        "title" => "required|string",
        "initial_price" => "required|integer",
        "description" => "string",
        "sleeve_condition" => "exists:conditions,id",
        "media_condition" => "exists:conditions,id",
        "sku" => "string",
        "rating" => "integer",
        "product_type_id" => "exists:product_types,id",
        "author" => "string",
        "genre_id" => "exists:genres,id",
        "edition" => "string",
        "discount_id" => "sometimes|nullable|exists:discounts",
        "image" => "required|mimes:image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/webp|max:10000"
    ]);
    $path = $request->file('image')->store('images', 'public');
    return Product::create([$request->all(), "filename" => basename($path), "url" => Storage::disk('public')->url($path)]);
}
```

I'm not really sure where it's all going wrong. I'm using Nuxt 3 and Laravel 9.